# for what reason this does not work properly (navmesh)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navmesh

```cs
private void moveto(Vector3 direction){
    bool possible = true;
    possible = UnityEngine.AI.NavMesh.CalculatePath(transform.position, direction, UnityEngine.AI.NavMesh.AllAreas, path);
    if(possible)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < path.corners.Length-1; i++)
            Debug.DrawLine(path.corners[i], path.corners[i+1], Color.red);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, path.corners[1] , myspeed * Time.deltaTime);
        path.ClearCorners();
    }
}
```

path thing is navmeshpath thing btw, I am new in both *unity* and *stackoverflow*.

I use this in enemy aid.

`drawline` shows a path, its ok.

then for what reason the object does strange movements? like going in circle, or running away from player after dash(object has a dash attack), even when doing bugged movement it still shows a perfect path from `drawray`, just does not follow the path and do random thing, maybe navmesh makes random waypoints just behind the object so I cannot see them??

movement code was directly going to player before, the change is now its a function and it calculates a path(every frame) and goes to first waypoint of that path

Comment: Just a note on your title, the vast majority of questions on Stack Overflow are "Why doesn't this work?" or "What's going wrong here?"  A _descriptive_ title would serve to differentiate your question from the hundreds posted around the same time and might attract readers better able to help you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Besides correcting @LanceU.Matthews what commented, to help you we really need to see more of the code; a lot of things could be causing the error, from alias bug, typos or logic errors. Anyway, are you trying to developing in the test-driven development paradigm? If not, try to embrace it, because TDD is the way to detect or even avoid these errors.